# Divided differences equality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, numerical-methods

Is there some easy way to see that $$\frac{f[a,\frac{a+b}{2},b,x]-f[a,\frac{a+b}{2},b,\frac{a+b}{2}]}{x-\frac{a+b}{2}}$$ in the 2nd line is equivalent to

$$f[a,\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a+b}{2},b,x]$$

in the 4th line?

[image: see here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, denote $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$. We have that the error in simpson's method is given by
$$
\int_a^b f[a,b,c,x] (x-a)(x-c)(x-b) dx
$$

If you now consider some $d \ne c$, you can see that

$$
f[d,a,b,c,x] = \frac{f[a,b,c,x]-f[a,b,c,d]}{x-d}
$$

and so

$$
f[a,b,c,x]=(x-d)f[a,b,c,d,x]+f[a,b,c,d]
$$

Back to the error expression, substituting $f[a,b,c,x]$, you get

$$
f[a,b,c,d]\underbrace{\int_a^b (x-a)(x-b)(x-c) dx}_{=0}+\int_a^b f[a,b,c,d,x](x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) dx
$$

Finally, taking the limit as $d \to c$, the error is given by

$$
\int_a^b f[a,b,c,c,x]\underbrace{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)^2}_{\leq 0} dx = \frac{f^{(4)}(\xi)}{4!} \underbrace{\int_a^b (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)^2dx}_{=\frac{(a-b)^5}{120}}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Before taking the limit: what motivation is there for you to know that "now i have to take the limit $d \to c$"? I want to know the reasoning for it, it comes a bit out of the blue for me.

Comment: @user711482 The use of the intermediate value theorem for integrals requires that one of the factors does not change sign. Since the $(x-c)$ term is the responsible for the change in sign, it seems an easy fix to "change it" to $(x-c)^2$.